# "Index was out of range" error in asp.net MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net MVC 5 project.I have two models Post and Comment having one to many relationship between them. In Post's Details view, I want to add comments in that Post. How can I do it without using any ViewModel? Only Post model is passed in the view. I want to access Comment and its properties by using Post model reference, after all they have one many relationship between them, Post model have Comment's reference.

Here is my code example
Details actions in Post's controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(Comment comment, string post_id)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(post_id); 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            var post = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == id);



            comment.post = post;

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(comment);
    }
    //
    // GET: /Post/Details/5

     public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
     {
         Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
         if (post == null)
         {
             return HttpNotFound();
         }
         return View(post);
     }
```

here is Details.schtml

```
  @model Blog.Models.Post

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

  <h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>Post</legend>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.title)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.title)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.body)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.body)
</div>

@for (int i = 0; i <Model.comments.Count; i++)
{

     <div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.comments[i].comment)
</div>

<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.comments[i].comment)

</div>
}

<h2>Comment</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Article</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">


            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

  </fieldset>
```

There is an error

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"

how can I successfully add comments ?

Comment: When and where does the error occur? Please provide a stack trace. Does `db.Posts.Find(id)` load the comments from the database?

Comment: it's run time error when I click on the Details button to show a Post's details. Yes. It loads

Comment: What line does the exception occur on?

Comment: on this line:    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment))

Answer (score 1):

The error itself pretty much explains the problem. On the line where you get the error the `Model.comments.Count` is out of the range. The indexation starts from 0 so the last comment should be retrieved this way `.... model => model.comments[Model.comments.Count - 1].comment`.

Comment: model => model.comments[Model.comments.Count - 1].. this line give me the last comment of my Post and also placed it in comment box, but I want to take a comment from user in that comment box which will be saved in the index (Model.comments.Count). If there is something wrong in my logic please help me. Thanks

Comment: Oh my bad I'm sorry, I thought u wonder why you get that error.
First of all a couple of suggestions. You should consider using `Foreach` it's a bit slower then `For` loop tho. In this specific case if you want to save a new comment I would suggest using model binding and use the `Comment` class as your model in Details.cshtml. If you need more specific answers or an example I would suggest you to look for some tutorials there are a lot of good ones. But if you want to use your Post model you can add a `string` property to your `Post` model and reference that property in the view.

Comment: Without seeing your models it's hard to say what to do exactly. Thanks

Comment: here is my model classes..............      public class Post
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comment> comments { get; set; }
    }                         public class Comment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public virtual Post post { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I did not get your point to "add a string property to your Post model". suppose I add it, them how can I use that property?

Comment: First of all could you please edit your question to add the models there too so that others can see them as well. So it's kinda odd from my perspective to use the `Post` as a model here. I would have used a view Model here which would have had a `string comment` property and afterwards I would have done the mapping in the controller. Is there any restrictions to not use any view model? Of course you can do the same in `Post` class as well but only if that class is **Domain Model** and not **Data Access Model**. My suggestion is to use a `PostViewModel` with an extra `string comment` property.

Comment: The thing is that your `Post` is Data Access Model and it should be as close to the actual DB data model as possible. So I wouldn't suggest to add that property there. Instead you should add it in the model view class.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is generated by the following line in your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment)
```

and will also be generated by the subsequent `EditorFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` methods.

Collection indexers are zero based, whereas `.Count()` returns the number of items in the collection. If say you collection contained 2 `Comment`, then you would access them as

```
model.Comments[0].comment
model.Comments[1].comment
```

but your `[Model.comments.Count]` equates to

```
model.Comments[2].comment
```

which throws the exception because your referring to the 3rd item in the collection (which does not exist). Even if you referred to an existing item in the collection, you code would fail because you would be posting back a collection (defined by the indexer) but you POST method only excepts a single object

It appears you wanting to add a new comment to the `Post` in which case you can either use a view model containing an additional property for `Comment`

```
public Comment NewComment { get; set; }
```

and then in you view, generate the form controls using

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewComment.comment)
```

and change the POST method signature to

```
public ActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix = "NewComment")]Comment comment, int post_id)
```

Note the use of the `Bind.Prefix` property which is necessary to strip the `"NewComment"` prefix from the name/value pair posted to the method. Note also that you can make the second parameter `int` and avoid the unnecessary conversion from `string` to `int` (although you do not appear to be generating a form control for property `post_id` so it will be `null` anyway).

An alternative would be to use `@Html.Action()` to call a child action method that returns a partial view (containing the form) based on a new `Comment`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `db.Posts.Find(id);`. you have given initial value for id in `public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)`. Check your code to be sure you always pass value to id.

Comment: This is not the problem, nor would it be the problem. He's checking if `post == null` and if so returning `HttpNotFound()`.

Comment: No. there is no problem. because I have checked out this by adding comments in a Post in a different way. then getting it's details by the same action but different code in view. There is something wrong in these lines.@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.comments[Model.comments.Count].comment))